# I do not see how $ \frac { 1 }{ 1-x } = \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty }{ { x }^{ n } } $

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I do not see how $$ \frac { 1 }{ 1-x } =\quad \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { x }^{ n } }  $$

for example, When x = 10
and n = 1

Then $$ \frac { 1 }{ 1-10 } \neq \quad { 10 }^{ 1 } $$

What am overlooking? What is clear way to show? $$ \frac { 1 }{ 1-x } =\quad \sum _{ n=0 }^{ \infty  }{ { x }^{ n } }$$

Comment: This is true when $|x|<1$

Comment: This is true only when the summation is valid i.e. $|x| < 1$.

Comment: Ah. This is what I am overlooking. The domain of x.

Comment: How are you putting $n=1$ here ?

Comment: I was just giving the second index to show my made up contradiction.

Comment: @user1787331 It's also fairly obvious that if $x \gt 1$ then the LHS is negative, while the RHS side is a sum of positive terms, so the equality can never hold. This kind of "reality checks" can often help.

Comment: My teacher wrote it down without showing the domain. So I took her word for it...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that we may still refer to this "identity" that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ when $x$ is unknown or simply an algebraic variable for use in [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can't choose just one $n$ to plug into the formula. $n$ isn't a variable, it's an index: you sum over all $n$, meaning
$$
\frac{1}{1 - x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots,
$$
when the right hand side converges (meaning you can only plug in certain $x$). If $\left|x\right| < 1$, you can show that this is true without much trouble: let $S_N = \sum_{n = 0}^N x^n$. Then $x S_N = \sum_{n = 0}^N x^{n+1}$. Then $S_N - x S_N = \sum_{n = 0}^N x^n - \sum_{n = 0}^N x^{n+1} = 1 - x^{N+1}$, and hence
$$
S_N = \frac{1 - x^{N+1}}{1 - x}.
$$
Taking the limit, we have
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} S_N = \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1 - x^{N+1}}{1 - x} = \frac{1}{1 - x},
$$
because $x^N\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$ if $\left|x\right| < 1$. By definition, $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n = \lim_{N\to\infty} S_N$, so you have your formula.

Comment: I suspect OP chose $n = 1$ to show that just one positive term already exceeds the negative result of the LHS, not actually looking for an equality—though it is a little hard to tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**-Sum it over finite terms and then take the limit

Answer (score -1):

$\sum _{n=0}^\infty x^n=1+x+x^2+\ldots $  which is a G.P. series with common ratio $x$

Hence $1+x+x^2+\ldots =\dfrac{1}{1-x} \text{if |x|<1}$

Comment: It doesn't converge if $|x|>1$.